# Private inner class access method

Tags: java

I made an example to access private method from the inner class and i am getting every time class not found exception.

```
   class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("Inner.Private");
            Method m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("foo");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(new Inner());
        }
     }

class Inner {
    private class Private {
        private void foo() {
            System.out.println("foo called");
        }
    }
}// end of Inner
```

I am getting an exception as below:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Inner.Private     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)

Any help would highly appreciate. Let me know why it's ignoring a inner class or any insight.

Comment: Make Test a public class.

Comment: It's `Inner$Private`.

Comment: In addition to @Pillar, `m.invoke(new Inner());` won't work since you're giving an `Inner` instance to a method of `Inner.Private`.

Comment: @theVoid yes i made it 'public class Test' still is given "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" .

Comment: this question is worded much better than "Give an arguments to main" I would never have searched that string for a question about inner classes.  not a duplicate question since title of Tunaki's suggestion would never turn up in a search.

Answer (score 0):

Inner classes must go **inside** its outer class.

```
public class Test {

    private class Inner {

        private void foo() {
            System.out.println("foo called");
        }
    }

    public void test()
            throws ClassNotFoundException,
            NoSuchMethodException,
            IllegalAccessException,
            IllegalArgumentException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        Inner inner = new Inner();
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.oldcurmudgeon.test.Test$Inner");
        Method m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("foo");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        m.invoke(inner);
    }
```

Comment: @Pillar How have they not resolved the issue? Please explain when giving feedback so people can improve answers.

Comment: @Pillar That is better, it's always better to explain. The whole purpose of this site is to help each other out. If you have an answer then you should have left it before it closed. Don't really on solely on some knowing what you mean by a comment. Your comment of "It's Inner$Private" had me puzzled for a minute as I had no idea what you were talking about, just thought you were a user on acid putting random words down

Comment: @Pillar et al - thanks for the feedback - I have tested the new code and it does now seem to do what was intended.